# How to put characters after number through setNumberFormat()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The result I am trying to obtain is if a number is above 999,999 it will show as "3 M". And when it's below 1,000,000 it will show as (100K). And the rest would be just number.

But I can't figure out how to put character after the number. I tried to  put the character inside single quote and double quote didn't work.

FYI, I am new to coding.

```
    function onOpen()

{
  var Menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  Menu.createMenu("Menu").addItem("Format numbers","myFunction").addToUi();

}


function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() .   
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange() .       
  range.setNumberFormat("[>999999]0.#,,;[>999]##0,;0"); 
}
```

Comment: In your question your asking for numbers `>=1000000 and <1000000` there is no other option.

Comment: In your code I thinking this `range.setNumberFormat("[>999999]0.#,,;[>999]##0,;0");` should be this `range.setNumberFormat("[>999999]"3M";[100000]"100K";####"); ` See example below

Comment: Fixed it btw. It was working without the third option. I just couldn't figure out how attach the characters (M,K) with it. The reason it was not working because I didn't use the quotes correctly.

Comment: I put the whole statement in the single quote and put the letters inside double quote and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Number Formats

I think this is what you going for:

```
function specialFormat() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()   
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();      
  range.setNumberFormat('[<3]"LOW";[>=10]"HIGH";####;'); 
}
```

Range before function runs:

[image]

Range after function runs:

[image]

- [NumberFormat Examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats#number_format_examples)

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't use quotation properly.  After making the whole statement into one quote and the characters into single quote it worked just fine.... thanks!!

Comment: I've never tried this before.  Thanks for the question.